# Type casting in spring program

Tags: spring

I am facing issue in spring program, the issue is Why type casting is applied in spring application?
below is the program for reference.

```
public class Test {
  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
          Hello obj= (Hello)context.getBean("hello");
          obj.getMessge();
       }
    
    }
```

Comment: Is that an *issue* or a *question*?

Answer (score 1):

The `getBean(String)` method returns an object of the type `Object`. Since you know that the method you annotated with `@Bean(name = "hello")` returns an instance of `Hello` you can safely cast getBean's return value to `Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object getBean(String name)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-) returns an instance of type Object; hence, you must cast it to whatever you expect it to return.

[`<T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) overloaded method can be used alternatively, and it will return the object of type `T`.

You can change your code as follows:

```
Hello obj = context.getBean("hello", Hello.class);
```

and in this case, you will not need to cast the returned object explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The getBean() method returns an object type. Since you know that the method you annotated with @Bean(name = "hello") returns an instance of Hello you can safely cast getBean's return value to Hello.